# JBoss EAP 6.3 crash System.out.println

Tags: jboss7.x, system.out

I have created a war application and it was tested both in weblogic 12c and Jboss EAP 6.2 successfully.
I changed application server, i moved to JBoss EAP 6.3 and the application could not work properly. Suddenly Jboss stopped to serve any requests and the existing requests were waiting for ever. 
I have started Jboss in debug mode from netbeans and i run my application in debug mode.

I have noticed that every time the server was stopping at the System.out.println(); command.

After server's crush/stuck, i interrupt the last thread which was at the log file and upon the interruption i see at the netbean's debugging console a notice:"stopped at AppenderSkeleton.java:231" The previous call at the code is a the line that calls system.out.println.

When i removed all the system.out.println from my code and i left only my log4j the application did not stuck again. I am still testing because i don't know for sure if this is the problem.

Does anyone else had the same problem? When the System.out.println was called one a time it seems that there is no problem, but when this method is called from multiple methods then it seems to stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use a custom log4j configuration in your deployment. It requires a special care as explained by the JBoss logging developer James Perkins in [this JBoss forum comment](https://developer.jboss.org/message/875508#875508).

Your problem could be related to changes between EAP 6.2 and EAP 6.3 introduced by following bugfix:

- [Bugzilla: System.out.println() doesn't work when using per-deployment logging](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1070453)

Other users experience similar issue as described in

- [Bugzilla: ConsoleAppenders can deadlock if included in application log4j configs](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196228)

If you have some additional info, feel free to comment on existing bugzillas or create a new one where you describe your application (mainly logging) configuration.

Comment: I think i am at the second case. After some debugging i think there is a dead lock between these two appenders. 
I used today log4j2 and i think the problem is over but i want to test it more the next days as i need to change a lot of things because i also use custom appenders and i will have a good idea at the end of this process. But your info helped me as i know that i have not done something tragic in my code.